# Using the nodes argument for centrality metrics in sna

Tags: r, sna, statnet

I am trying to calculate centrality metrics for a specific node within a graph using `statnet` (I can't just use `igraph` since it doesn't have certain metrics I'd like).

How do I use the nodes argument of these functions to specify this? For example, take `prestige`

```
# use the faux.magnolia.high dataset from ergm (1461 vertices and 974 edges)
library("ergm")
data(“faux.magnolia.high”)

# Try calculating for node 1
sna::prestige(faux.magnolia.high, nodes = 1, gmode = "graph")
```

> 1

```
# Try calculating for node 2
sna::prestige(faux.magnolia.high, nodes = 2, gmode = "graph")
```

> NA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug in degree-related versions of `prestige`. This will work but calculations will be done on the whole graph:

```
sna::prestige(faux.magnolia.high, gmode = "graph")[2]
```

See Skye's full response on the statnet mailing list:
http://mailman13.u.washington.edu/pipermail/statnet_help/2016/002175.html